# Pointers Pointing at 2D Arrays and being declared in other functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

This is for an assignment.

I know how to call a 1D array. As shown

```
char string[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
char *Ptrstring = &string[0];
```

and when you want to use it in a function

```
int different function(char *Ptrstr) {
    *(Ptrstr+5)=*(Ptrstr+1)
}
```

I get the gist of

```
char string[2][5] = { {'a','b','c','d','e'}, {'f','g','h','i','j'} };
char *Ptrstring = &string[0][0];
```

but how am I supposed to change its value/char inside of it in a different function?

Answer (score 1):

```
func(char str[][5])
{
  //Access the 2D array
}
```

OR

```
func(char *p)
{
  //Access each row
}
```

Call should be

```
func(string[i]);
```

Comment: @haccks I was totally puzzled looking at the down-vote on this but just ignored it which doesn't make any sense

Comment: @herljoshualara You can't change your question on the go .. The second part of answer shows accessing row by row.

Comment: so does this mean..  i can't really access a 2d array by its column? in another function?

Comment: @herljoshualara You need to loop through each to to get respective columns by passing the whole 2D array